# How to use Schema.from_dict() for nested dictionaries?

Tags: marshmallow

I am trying to create a Schema class using nested dictionaries that has some list as elements. However when I do a dumps() Only the top level elements are dumped.

Have a rest api that returns a list of certain things,eg. list of users. but the schema is such that certain aggregate details are sent at the top level, the data looks something like this. This is what i am expecting as output:

```
   {
        "field1": 5,
        "field2": false,
        "field3": {
            "field4": 40,
            "field5": [
                        {
                            "field6": "goo goo gah gah",
                            "field7": 99.341879,
                            "field8": {
                                "field9": "goo goo gah gah",
                                "field10": "goo goo gah gah"
                        }
             }]
         }
    }
```

Heres my code:

```
MySchema = Schema.from_dict(
   {
        "field1": fields.Int(),
        "field2": fields.Bool(),
        "field3": {
            "field4": fields.Int(),
            "field5": [
                        {
                            "field6": fields.Str(),
                            "field7": fields.Float(),
                            "field8": {
                                "field9": fields.Str(),
                                "field10": fields.Str()
                        }
             }]
         }
    }            
)

#Then use it like:

response = MySchema().dumps(data)
```

Actual result:

```
"{\"field1\": 5, \"field2\": false}"
```

Answer (score 5):

## Option 1

You're looking for several nested schemas, interconnected through [`fields.Nested`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Nested):

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields


Field8Schema = Schema.from_dict({
    "field9": fields.Str(), 
    "field10": fields.Str()
})

Field5Schema = Schema.from_dict({
    "field6": fields.Str(),
    "field7": fields.Float(),
    "field8": fields.Nested(Field8Schema),
})

Field3Schema = Schema.from_dict({
    "field4": fields.Int(), 
    "field5": fields.List(fields.Nested(Field5Schema))
})

MySchema = Schema.from_dict({
    "field1": fields.Int(),
    "field2": fields.Bool(),
    "field3": fields.Nested(Field3Schema),
})

MySchema().dump(data)

# {'field2': False,
#  'field1': 5,
#  'field3': {'field4': 40,
#   'field5': [{'field6': 'goo goo gah gah',
#     'field8': {'field9': 'goo goo gah gah', 'field10': 'goo goo gah gah'},
#     'field7': 99.341879}]}}
```

## Option 2

If the nesting won't be that deep, it might be simpler to use [`decorators`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#module-marshmallow.decorators), i.e. nest and unnest data as [suggested in the docs](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#module-marshmallow.decorators):

```py
class UserSchema(Schema):
    @pre_load(pass_many=True)
    def remove_envelope(self, data, many, **kwargs):
        namespace = 'results' if many else 'result'
        return data[namespace]

    @post_dump(pass_many=True)
    def add_envelope(self, data, many, **kwargs):
        namespace = 'results' if many else 'result'
        return {namespace: data}
```

It feels it fits your case nicely.

## Comments

I'd suggest not to use `from_dict` as it is less readable for such a complex data, and instead switch to a class-based schema.

There's plenty of [good examples](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nesting.html) of nesting in the docs.

Comment: +1 for class-based schemas. from_dict is a tool function meant to be used in 3rd-party libs. I'd avoid pre_load/post_dump when things can be done with simple  marshmallow schemas, as schemas are more structured, more introspectable. Also, I'd use List(Nested()) rather than Nested(many=True) as the latter will be deprecated (someday).

Comment: Wondering out loud. I'm not familiar with from_dict, but the OP's case seems legit, though. Could be a bug or enhancement request.

Comment: from_dict was added in https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/pull/1322 and it does not create Nested fields for fields in containers (lists, dicts, etc.).

Comment: Good point @Jérôme, there's a potential to contribute it back to marshmallow, as the change is straightforward and purely mechanical.

Comment: I'm not sure it is straightforward. You may discuss it in the bugtracker before investing too much work in this. (marsmallow co-maintainer speaking)

Comment: Oh, nice! That's a modest profile picture you have there :) btw, I updated the code snippet to `List(Nested())` as suggested